# I want to give only numbers in the field is it possible without any validations

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to only allow **numbers** in the text field, text cannot be entered. Is it possible to do this without any validations?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label ">Sort Order</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sort_order" name="sort_order" placeholder="Sort Order">
    </div>
</div>
```

If text enters show a message: "please enter only numbers".

Comment: `<input type="number">` doesn't count?

Comment: it is accepting negative values as well,i dont want like that any alternative way

Comment: Put a `min` tag. `<input type="number" min="0">`

Comment: let me  in that way

Comment: Thank you so Much for suggestion it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

use    input type="number"

Note: type="number" is not supported in IE9 and earlier.

Comment: then what is the best solution for it..?

Comment: @M.DWaheed if you need to support IE9 or earlier then you would have to write validation code. I would advise, if you haven't already, that you write some server-side validation code in PHP anyway. Client-side validation, including setting things like `<input type="number">` is very easy for a malicious user to bypass

Comment: can you give a example of validation.i am new to php

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label ">Sort Order</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="number"  min="1" class="form-control" id="sort_order" name="sort_order" placeholder="Sort Order">
</div>
</div>
```